# how to disable "transport.vfs.ActionAfterProcess" in WSO2 VFS Proxy

Tags: wso2, wso2-esb

Is there any way to disable the paramater "transport.vfs.ActionAfterProcess" in VFS Proxy in WSO2 ESB? In my case I don't want the file to be moved or deleted. 
How can i do this? 
I tried not to include the "transport.vfs.ActionAfterProcess" parameter, but I think it has a default value so the file still moved or deleted.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution to this is to have the file moved back to the same directory, but if you have a polling system where you constantly check the input directory for new files, then you could have the processed filed saved with a different naming convention that would be filtered when files are taken in for processing.